# OneToMany or OneToOne, I'm in the right or wrong path?

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, mapping

I have this DB model:
 [image: single database]

Then I made this entities (I just leave the relation part since the other isn't relevant on the topic):

`Orders.php`

```
class Orders {
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Person", inversedBy="orders")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="person_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * */
    protected $person;

    public function setPerson(Person $person)
    {
        $this->person = $person;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getPerson()
    {
        return $this->person;
    }

}
```

`Person.php`

```
class Person {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="NaturalPerson", mappedBy="person")
     * */
    private $naturals;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="LegalPerson", mappedBy="person")
     * */
    private $legals;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Orders", mappedBy="person")
     * */
    private $orders;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->naturals = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->legals = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->orders = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getNaturals()
    {
        return $this->naturals;
    }

    public function getLegals()
    {
        return $this->legals;
    }

    public function getOrders()
    {
        return $this->orders;
    }

}
```

`NaturalPerson.php`

```
class NaturalPerson {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Person", inversedBy="naturals")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="person_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $person;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="identification_type", type="ci_type", nullable=false)
     * @DoctrineAssert\Enum(entity="Tanane\FrontendBundle\DBAL\Types\CIType")
     */
    protected $identification_type;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="ci", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $ci;

    public function setPerson(Person $person)
    {
        $this->person = $person;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getPerson()
    {
        return $this->person;
    }

    public function setIdentificationType($identification_type)
    {
        $this->identification_type = $identification_type;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getIdentificationType()
    {
        return $this->identification_type;
    }

    public function setCI($ci)
    {
        $this->ci = $ci;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getCI()
    {
        return $this->ci;
    }

}
```

I omitted `LegalPerson` since it's pretty much the same as `NaturalPerson` so here is the problem. The mapping looks good but how I do get related records from `Orders`?

The idea behind this is for each `Orders` I need to know to which `Person` belongs too (the Orders) and also the extra information stored at `NaturalPerson` or `LegalPerson` depending on `person.type`.

See this code:

```
public function getOrdersAction()
{
    $response = array();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entities = $em->getRepository("FrontendBundle:Orders")->findAll();

    if (!$entities)
    {
        $response['message'] = "No se encontraron resultados";
    }

    $orders = array();
    foreach ($entities as $entity)
    {

        $personType = $entity->getPerson()->getPersonType();

        $order = array();
        $order[] = $entity->getNickname();

        // Here I'm trying to access to `Naturals` methods from `Orders` 
        if ($personType == 1)
        {
            $order[] = $entity->getPerson()->getNaturals()[0]->getIdentificationType() . $entity->getPerson()->getNaturals()[0]->getCI();
        }
        elseif ($personType == 2)
        {
            $order[] = $entity->getPerson()->getLegals()[0]->getIdentificationType() . $entity->getPerson()->getLegals()[0]->getRIF();
        }

        $orders[] = $order;
    }

    $response['data'] = $orders;
    return new JsonResponse($response);
}
```

But I get this error:

> Error: Call to a member function getIdentificationType() on a
>   non-object in
>   /var/www/html/tanane/src/Tanane/BackendBundle/Controller/OrderController.php
>   line 115

Maybe my mapping is wrong since I should have `OneToOne` between `Person` and `NaturalPerson` (and that sounds wrong to my logic as DER shows) or maybe is not, but then I don't know how to fetch related properties for just one record, I read docs [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html) and also in [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html) but they didn't talk about this part or I don't see it, any advice? ideas? tips?

**Trying to use Repositories and DQL to solve the problem**

I'm building a function in a `Repository` class to fetch the data and not get to complicated as apparently my problem is, so I did this:

```
public function getOrders($person_type = 1)
{
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

    $qb
            ->select('ord.*, ps.*')
            ->from("FrontendBundle:Orders", "ord")
            ->join('FrontendBUndle:Person', 'ps', 'WITH', 'ps.id = ord.person_id')
            ->orderBy('ord.created', 'DESC');

    if ($person_type == 1)
    {
        $qb
                ->select('np.*')
                ->join('FrontendBundle:NaturalPerson', 'np', 'WITH', 'ps.id = np.person'); // Join NaturalPerson table
    }
    elseif ($person_type == 2)
    {
        $qb
                ->select('lp.*')
                ->join('FrontendBundle:LegalPerson', 'lp', 'WITH', 'ps.id = lp.person'); // Join NaturalPerson table
    }

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

I'm not tested yet so maybe it won't works but, if the idea is to get the extra information for both tables, then using this DQL I made how I pass the `$person_type` which is inside `Person` table? This is getting a little complicated, at least for me

**Running a raw query to see if columns are NULL**

I build this simple query just for test if results are `NULL`:

```
SELECT
    ord.id,
    ord.person_id as ord_person_id,
  ord.nickname,
  ps.id,
  ps.description,
  np.person_id as natural_person_id,
  np.identification_type,
    np.ci
FROM
    orders ord
LEFT JOIN person ps ON ord.person_id = ps.id
LEFT JOIN natural_person np ON np.person_id = ps.id
WHERE
    ps.person_type = 1;
```

And this what query returns:

[image]

So there is not NULL columns in there

**CRUD for create new Orders**

```
// Set Person entity
$entityPerson = new Person();
$person_type === 1 ? $entityPerson->setDescription($orders['nat']['person']['description']) : $entityPerson->setDescription($orders['leg']['person']['description']);
$person_type === 1 ? $entityPerson->setContactPerson($orders['nat']['person']['contact_person']) : $entityPerson->setContactPerson($orders['leg']['person']['contact_person']);
$entityPerson->setPersonType($person_type);

$em->persist($entityPerson);
$em->flush();

...

if ($person_type === 1)
{
    // Set NaturalPerson entity
    $entityNatural = new NaturalPerson();
    $entityNatural->setIdentificationType($orders['nat']['identification_type']);
    $entityNatural->setCI($orders['nat']['ci']);

    $em->persist($entityNatural);
    $em->flush();
}
elseif ($person_type === 2)
{
    // Set LegalPerson entity
    $entityLegal = new LegalPerson();
    $entityLegal->setIdentificationType($orders['leg']['identification_type']);
    $entityLegal->setRIF($orders['leg']['rif']);

    $em->persist($entityLegal);
    $em->flush();
}
```

Comment: I guess `Person` could either be a `NaturalPerson` OR a `LegalPerson`, right? Or can it be both?

Comment: No, it just can be one of both a Person is Natural or is Legal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `LegalPerson` and `NaturalPerson` are specializations of `Person` I would recommend using what Doctrine calls Class Table Inheritance ([documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance)).

You would have:

`Person.php`

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="person")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *     "natural" = "NaturalPerson",
 *     "legal" = "LegalPerson",
 * })
 */
class Person {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Orders", mappedBy="person")
     * */
    private $orders;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->orders = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getOrders()
    {
        return $this->orders;
    }

}
```

`NaturalPerson.php`

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="natural_person")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class NaturalPerson extends Person {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="identification_type", type="ci_type", nullable=false)
     * @DoctrineAssert\Enum(entity="Tanane\FrontendBundle\DBAL\Types\CIType")
     */
    protected $identification_type;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="ci", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $ci;

    public function setIdentificationType($identification_type)
    {
        $this->identification_type = $identification_type;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getIdentificationType()
    {
        return $this->identification_type;
    }

    public function setCI($ci)
    {
        $this->ci = $ci;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getCI()
    {
        return $this->ci;
    }
}
```

`Order.php` stays the same.

As you can see, now both `NaturalPerson` and `LegalPerson` extend `Person`. Since you've changed your entities definition, you'll have to update your database schema.

Now, in your `Controller` you only have to do this:

```
foreach ($entities as $entity)
{
    $person = $entity->getPerson();

    $order = array();
    $order[] = $entity->getNickname();

    if ($person instanceof NaturalPerson)
    {
        $order[] = $person->getIdentificationType() . $person->getCI();
    }
    else // it has to be LegalPerson
    {
        $order[] = $person->getIdentificationType() . $person->getRIF();
    }

    $orders[] = $order;
}
```

Don't forget to add the `use` statement for `NaturalPerson`!

This way you only work with instances of either `NaturalPerson` or `LegalPerson`. I'm sure you can further improve this.

Lastly, you will have to change your CRUD for this. You don't work directly with `Person` anymore (in fact, it should be `abstract`), so now you need to handle CRUD for `NaturalPerson` and for `LegalPerson` separately. Each will have its `Type`, `Controller`, views, etc.

Your code would now look like this:

```
if ($person_type === 1)
{
    $entityPerson = new NaturalPerson();
    $entityPerson->setDescription($orders['nat']['person']['description']);
    $entityPerson->setContactPerson($orders['nat']['person']['contact_person']);
    $entityPerson->setIdentificationType($orders['nat']['identification_type']);
    $entityPerson->setCI($orders['nat']['ci']);

    $em->persist($entityPerson);
    $em->flush();
}
elseif ($person_type === 2)
{
    $entityPerson = new LegalPerson();
    $entityPerson->setDescription($orders['leg']['person']['description']);
    $entityPerson->setContactPerson($orders['leg']['person']['contact_person']);
    $entityPerson->setIdentificationType($orders['leg']['identification_type']);
    $entityPerson->setRIF($orders['leg']['rif']);

    $em->persist($entityPerson);
    $em->flush();
}
```

Comment: I like more this approach and in deep if you notice my model that's exactly what I'm trying to do by using SQL Antipattern Class Table Inheritance I don't know this was covered by Doctrine, now I know, anyway I get this error: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't0.discr' in 'field list'` do I need to run any command? Maybe for update the database?

Comment: Ok, I've updated the schema but now any time I try to insert a new record I got this other error `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'discr' cannot be null ` what should I set on that field?

Comment: Oops! I forgot to explain that part. I will update my answer shortly.

Comment: Great, thx, I was reading the docs you leave and I see this: `When you do not use the SchemaTool to generate the required SQL you should know that deleting a class table inheritance makes use of the foreign key property ON DELETE CASCADE in all database implementations. A failure to implement this yourself will lead to dead rows in the database.` can you explain a bit this based on my model? What changes should I made for not incur this?

Comment: Using this architecture you'll end up with three tables: person, natural_person and legal_person. If you persist a new a `NaturalPerson` Doctrine will add a row in `natural_person` and another one in `person`.

What the doc is telling you is that if you delete the row in `natural_person` by other means (like doing it manually in phpMyAdmin), there will still be a row left in `person`, and since nobody is using it anymore, it's called a dead row.

Comment: I added some extra info about how I create/insert new records in DB (the create part) can you take a look? I get lost at this point, your latest paragraph confused me

Comment: And how do I persist first `NaturalPerson` and after `Person`? What about with `Person` columns? How this should be handled?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, a problem in other. You can forget to assign `NaturalPerson` or `LegalPerson` to `Person` entity. So you need to check it before calling `getIdentificationType()`:

```
if($personType == 1){
    if(null !== $natural = $entity->getPerson()->getNaturals()[0]){
       $order[] = $natural->getIdentificationType() . $natural->getCI();
    }
}elseif($personType == 2){
    if(null !== $legal = $entity->getPerson()->getLegals()[0]){
       $order[] = $legal->getIdentificationType() . $legal->getRIF();
    }
}
```