# Variable has value but form display empty, why?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm editing a object using this code:

```
public function editAction($id = null)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $order = $em->getRepository('FrontendBundle:Orders')->find($id);
    $type = $order->getPerson()->getPersonType() === 1 ? "natural" : "legal";

    ladybug_dump_die($order);

    $orderForm = $this->createForm(new OrdersType(array($type)), $order, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('update-order', array('id' => $id)),
        'method' => 'POST',
        ));

    return  array(
        'entity' => $order,
        "form" => $orderForm->createView(),
        'id' => $id
    );
}
```

All there works fine except that I'm not know/find how to display object `Person` values. If you take a look at the picture I've attached here you'll notice that `Person` comes with values:

[image: Controller Debug]

In the other side I did the same but at Twig template and I make a debug to the `form` var and I get this:

[image: Twig Render]

Now at this point I'm confused and come with two possible ideas, that I hope, someone help me to develop or at least understand.

1. Find a solution and display the right form using all the info from the `entity` I'm passing to the view. This is the ideal and I'll like to work on this in order to learn, so help?
2. Get the `Person` object in controller and create a second form by passing `Person` object values, this should work but them I'll need a lot of changes in `update` function since forms will travel separately.

What I need here is to get the `NaturalPersonType` or `LegalPersonType` embedded in `OrdersType` any time I edit a existent `Orders` because right now I don't know how to display the widget in the twig template. Notice at the end the form I'm talking about in this case is a `NaturalPersonType` rendered but without values:

[image]

**Adding OrdersType FormType**

```
class OrdersType extends AbstractType {

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $register_type;

    public function __construct($register_type)
    {
        $this->register_type = $register_type;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
                ->add('nickname', 'text', array(
                    'required' => FALSE,
                    'label' => "Nickname/Seudónimo",
                    'trim' => TRUE,
                    'attr' => array(
                        'class' => 'nickname'
                    )
                ))
                ->add('email', 'email', array(
                    'required' => TRUE,
                    'label' => "Correo Electrónico",
                    'trim' => TRUE
                ))
                ->add('phone', 'tel', array(
                    'required' => TRUE,
                    'label' => 'Números de teléfono (separados por "/")',
                    'trim' => TRUE,
                    'default_region' => 'VE',
                    'format' => PhoneNumberFormat::NATIONAL
                ))
                ->add('fiscal_address', 'textarea', array(
                    'required' => TRUE,
                    'label' => 'Dirección'
                ))
                ->add('shipping_address', 'textarea', array(
                    'required' => TRUE,
                    'label' => 'Dirección de Envío'
                ))
                ->add('shipping_from', 'choice', array(
                    'label' => 'Compañía de Encomiendas',
                    'choices' => SFType::getChoices(),
                    'empty_value' => '-- SELECCIONAR --'
                ))
                ->add('payment_type', 'entity', array(
                    'class' => 'CommonBundle:PaymentType',
                    'property' => 'name',
                    'required' => TRUE,
                    'label' => 'Forma de Pago',
                    'empty_value' => '-- SELECCIONAR --'
                ))
                ->add('order_amount', 'number', array(
                    'label' => 'Monto',
                    'required' => TRUE,
                    'precision' => 2
                ))
                ->add('bank', 'entity', array(
                    'class' => 'CommonBundle:Bank',
                    'property' => 'name',
                    'required' => TRUE,
                    'label' => 'Banco',
                    'empty_value' => '-- SELECCIONAR --'
                ))
                ->add('transaction', 'text', array(
                    'required' => TRUE,
                    'label' => 'No. Transacción'
                ))
                ->add('comments', 'textarea', array(
                    'required' => FALSE,
                    'label' => 'Comentarios'
                ))
                ->add('secure', 'checkbox', array(
                    'label' => FALSE,
                    'required' => FALSE,
                    'value' => 1,
                    'mapped' => FALSE
                ))
                ->add('lives_in_ccs', 'checkbox', array(
                    'label' => false,
                    'required' => false,
                    'mapped' => FALSE,
                    'value' => 1,
                ))
                ->add('suscribe_mail_list', 'checkbox', array(
                    'label' => FALSE,
                    'required' => FALSE,
                    'value' => 1,
                    'mapped' => FALSE
        ));

        if ($this->register_type[0] == "natural")
        {
            $builder->add('nat', new NaturalPersonType(), array('mapped' => FALSE));
        }
        elseif ($this->register_type[0] == "legal")
        {
            $builder->add('leg', new LegalPersonType(), array('mapped' => FALSE));
        }
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Tanane\FrontendBundle\Entity\Orders',
            'render_fieldset' => FALSE,
            'show_legend' => FALSE,
            'intention' => 'orders_form'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'orders';
    }

}
```

**Adding NaturalPersonType**

```
<?php

namespace Tanane\FrontendBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Tanane\FrontendBundle\DBAL\Types\CIType;

class NaturalPersonType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        $builder
                ->add('identification_type', 'choice', array(
                    'label' => 'Número de Cédula',
                    'choices' => CIType::getChoices()
                ))
                ->add('ci', 'number', array(
                    'required' => true,
                    'label' => false,
                    'attr' => array(
                        'maxlength' => 8,
                    ))
                )
                ->add('person', new PersonType(), array('mapped' => FALSE));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Tanane\FrontendBundle\Entity\NaturalPerson'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'natural_person';
    }

}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Could you please describe exactly the result you want to get? Also, it would be useful to see your `Type`'s code.

Comment: @FyodorX I added some extra info take a look and if you need something else let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `Type`. As you can see, the `mapped` option is set to `false` for both `nat` and `leg`. This means that **Symfony** will not connect those fields with your entity, so they are empty when you render the view.

I guess you did it that way because you don't have either of those properties in your model, but you *do* have `person`. What you need to do is to map `NaturalPersonType` or `LegalPersonType` to `person`.

The easiest way to do that in your case would be to replace the last lines of your `OrdersType`'s `buildForm()` with this:

```
    if ($this->register_type[0] == "natural")
    {
        $builder->add('person', new NaturalPersonType(), array('label' => FALSE));
    }
    elseif ($this->register_type[0] == "legal")
    {
        $builder->add('person', new LegalPersonType(), array('label' => FALSE));
    }
```

Comment: If I do this then I get this error: `Neither the property "nat" nor one of the methods "getNat()", "nat()", "isNat()", "hasNat()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "Tanane\FrontendBundle\Entity\Orders".`. To get a full view for my entities mapping refer to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25713074/onetomany-or-onetoone-im-in-the-right-or-wrong-path) since I'm using Doctrine **Class Table Inheritance**, so how I get this working?

Comment: Are you sure both fields are called `person`? `nat` shouldn't be around anymore.

Comment: in this case yes since this is a testing data loaded from Fixtures and yes all belongs to `NaturalPersonType`, what you get in mind to fix the issue?

Comment: Could you post `NaturalPersonType`?

Comment: Yes, added to main post, take a look

Comment: You're adding a field called `nat` to your form somewhere.

Comment: Yes, you're right take a look at `OrdersType.php` at end? I add `nat` or `leg` depending on the type, it's wrong? How I can fix this?

Comment: You have to replace that with the code I provided in my answer! Sorry, I thought it was clear.

Comment: I'm still having some issues here, see I'm rendering the field as `{{ form_widget(form.person.person.description) }}` and it renders right (without errors) but with no values and if you take a look at the first image, it has values, so, what I'm doing wrong in this case?

Comment: That's probably because of this line `->add('person', new PersonType(), array('mapped' => FALSE));` in `NaturalPersonType`. If you want, post this as a new question along with `NaturalPersonType`, `LegalPersonType` and `PersonType`'s code.

Comment: done [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25837475/form-values-is-empty-not-value-after-render-the-widget-on-a-form)