# Form values is empty (not value) after render the widget on a form

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I've this Form:

**OrdersType**

```
class OrdersType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // Others $builder fields goes here
        if ($this->register_type[0] == "natural")
        {
            $builder->add('person', new NaturalPersonType(), array('label' => FALSE));
        }
        elseif ($this->register_type[0] == "legal")
        {
            $builder->add('person', new LegalPersonType(), array('label' => FALSE));
        }
    }
}
```

**PersonType**

```
class PersonType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
                ->add('description', 'text', array(
                    'required' => TRUE,
                    'label' => FALSE
                ))
                ->add('contact_person', 'text', array(
                    'required' => FALSE,
                    'label' => 'Persona de Contacto'
        ));
    }
}
```

This is what I'm doing in the controller:

```
public function editAction($id = null)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $order = $em->getRepository('FrontendBundle:Orders')->find($id);
    $type = $order->getPerson()->getPersonType() === 1 ? "natural" : "legal";

    $orderForm = $this->createForm(new OrdersType(array($type)), $order, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('update-order', array('id' => $id)),
        'method' => 'POST',
        ));

    return  array(
        'entity' => $order,
        "form" => $orderForm->createView(),
        'id' => $id
    );
}
```

Then in my view I'm rendering fields as follow:

```
{{ form_widget(form.person.person.description) }}
```

The code renders the field right but without values and yes, it has values, where is the error? This are the others Forms I'm using:

**LegalPersonType**

```
class LegalPersonType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
                ->add('rif', 'text', array(
                    'required' => true,
                    'label' => false,
                    'attr' => array(
                        'maxlength' => 10,
                    ))
                )
                ->add('identification_type', 'choice', array(
                    'label' => FALSE,
                    'choices' => RifType::getChoices(),
                    'attr' => array(
                        'class' => 'toSelect2'
                    )
                ))
                ->add('person', new PersonType(), array('label' => FALSE));
    }
}
```

**Working on mapping**

**PersonType**

```
class PersonType extends AbstractType {
    ....
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Tanane\FrontendBundle\Entity\Person',
            'inherit_data' => true
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'person';
    }
}
```

**NaturalPersonType**

```
class NaturalPersonType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        $builder
                ->add('identification_type', 'choice', array(
                    'label' => 'Número de Cédula',
                    'choices' => CIType::getChoices()
                ))
                ->add('ci', 'number', array(
                    'required' => true,
                    'label' => false,
                    'attr' => array(
                        'maxlength' => 8,
                    ))
                )
                ->add('person', new PersonType(), array(
                    'label' => FALSE,
                    'data_class' => 'Tanane\FrontendBundle\Entity\NaturalPerson'
        ));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Tanane\FrontendBundle\Entity\NaturalPerson'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'natural_person';
    }
}
```

If I remove the `setDefaultOptions` method from `NaturalPersonType` I get this error:

> The form's view data is expected to be of type scalar, array or an
>   instance of \ArrayAccess, but is an instance of class
>   Tanane\FrontendBundle\Entity\NaturalPerson. You can avoid this error
>   by setting the "data_class" option to
>   "Tanane\FrontendBundle\Entity\NaturalPerson" or by adding a view
>   transformer that transforms an instance of class
>   Tanane\FrontendBundle\Entity\NaturalPerson to scalar, array or an
>   instance of \ArrayAccess.

If I leave as it's I get this other:

> Method "description" for object "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does
>   not exist in
>   /var/www/html/tanane/src/Tanane/BackendBundle/Resources/views/Order/edit.html.twig
>   at line 134

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `PersonType` is not being mapped correctly to your entity.

Since it's being used both by `LegalPersonType` and `NaturalPersonType` to handle some of their properties, I would define it as `parent` of those two. This can be achieved by using the `inherit_data` option ([documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/inherit_data_option.html)).

Your code would look something like this:

**PersonType**

```
class PersonType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
                ->add('description', 'text', array(
                    'required' => TRUE,
                    'label' => FALSE
                ))
                ->add('contact_person', 'text', array(
                    'required' => FALSE,
                    'label' => 'Persona de Contacto'
        ));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'inherit_data' => true,
        ));
    }
}
```

Note that you should remove the `data_class` option from `setDefaultOptions()`.

**LegalPersonType**

```
class LegalPersonType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
                ->add('rif', 'text', array(
                    'required' => true,
                    'label' => false,
                    'attr' => array(
                        'maxlength' => 10,
                    ))
                )
                ->add('identification_type', 'choice', array(
                    'label' => FALSE,
                    'choices' => RifType::getChoices(),
                    'attr' => array(
                        'class' => 'toSelect2'
                    )
                ))
                ->add('data', new PersonType(), array(
                    'label'      => FALSE,
                    'data_class' => 'YourBundle\Entity\LegalPerson',
                ));
    }
}
```

Your `NaturalPersonType` would look similar to `LegalPersonType`.

Now, you can do this in your view:

```
{{ form_widget(form.person.data.description) }}
```

Comment: I added the result of testing to the main post, take a look but it's not working

Comment: Remove `'data_class' => 'Tanane\FrontendBundle\Entity\Person',` from `PersonType`. Leave `setDefaultOptions` in `NaturalPersonType`. Now, what's on line 134 in Order/edit.html.twig?

Comment: Ok, I do what you said and error still and in line 134 I have this `{{ form_widget(form.person.description) }}`, do I need to clear the cache or not?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Basically, change `->add('person', new PersonType(), array(` for this `->add('data', new PersonType(), array(` in your `NaturalPersonType`. Now, on your view do this `{{ form_widget(form.person.data.description) }}`

Comment: yeah I already get it by trying this `{{ form_widget(form.person.person.description) }}` and it works, thanks, let me see if that doesn't break my others stuff